# hitTest doesn't get called in NSCell subclass

Tags: objective-c, hittest, nscell

I'm working on a subclass of `NSCell` for my project.

This subclass has, in some situation a `NSButtonCell` drawn on its view, with this :

```
- (void)drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {

... 
    if (self.mode == PMVersatileCellButton) {
        [_button drawWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
inView:controlView];
    } else {

...

    }

    [super drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
}
```

No prob. about the drawing, the problem is respond to click on the button !

I'm trying to do this with :

```
- (NSUInteger)hitTestForEvent:(NSEvent *)event inRect:(NSRect)frame ofView:(NSView *)controlView {

    NSLog(@"hitTest !");

    return [super hitTestForEvent:event inRect:frame ofView:controlView];

}
```

And :

```
+ (BOOL)prefersTrackingUntilMouseUp {
    return YES;
}
```

`- (BOOL)startTrackingAt:(NSPoint) inView:(NSView *)`

`- (BOOL)trackMouse:(NSEvent *) inRect:(NSRect) ofView:(NSView *) untilMouseUp:(BOOL)`

`- (BOOL)continueTracking:(NSPoint) at:(NSPoint) inView:(NSView *)`

`- (void)stopTracking:(NSPoint) at:(NSPoint) inView:(NSView *) mouseIsUp:(BOOL)`

But hitTest or any others never get called...

Only `+ (BOOL)prefersTrackingUntilMouseUp` get called, which doesn't help me so much...

Any idea ? ^^